# Eager loading association but limit return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

It seems like a simple query but I just can't nail it.

Basically it boils down to the age old concept of a categories having posts. The expected associations are in place, a category has_many posts whilst a post belongs to a category.

I want to retrieve all the categories with their posts but limit the number of posts to 10.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that you can do with raw SQL as LIMIT's are on the total dataset size, not anything else.

The only way of doing this purely by SQL is to create a fake id column in your join and filter than when it comes out which is something that implementation wise is incredibly dependant on the database server you are using.

The alternatives as either get all categories and posts and cut the recordset down, or get all categories and iteratively get 10 posts as Joerg suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to retrieve them all in one SQL statement? Or is it ok to lazy load them when you need them?

In which case

```
Category.all
```

will get all your categories, and stepping through them to get your posts could simply be

```
Category.all.each do |category|
  category.posts.limit(10)
end
```

Would this not be enough?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid N+1 queries, that is how it is currently working but it means many queries are performed to render the page when it could be (I think) be performed in 1 query.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible unfortunately - as, like Neil said - limit is applied to the whole dataset. You could possibly construct a SQL statement (depending on your DB and version) collecting the posts in subqueries with limit - but it might work out to be a similar amount of effort for your DB, however, with a possible readability penalty. I also wouldn't suggest getting all the data in one dataset, and then in Ruby chop it to your requirements -  that would result in a massive performance hit as each object - and a lot of unnecessary objects will need to be instantiated.